# Testing minimal docker containers with healthcheck

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have 5 containers running one after another. First 3, (ABC) are very minimal. ABC containers need to be health checked, but curl,wget cannot be run on them, so currently I just run `test:[CMD-SHELL], "whoami || exit 1"` in docker-compose.yml. Which seems to bring them to a healthy state. Other 2 (DE) dependent on ABC to be healthy are being checked using `test: [CMD-SHELL] , "curl --fail http://localhost"` command. My question is how can I properly check health of those minimal containers, without using curl, wget etc. ?

Comment: I guess no other way for that.

Comment: that depends on the services running in the containers....

Comment: Services are swaggerdocs, ldap and mongodb @LinPy

Answer (score 3):

I use the following command for docker health check in keycloak:

```
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/localhost/80;echo -e "GET /health/live HTTP/1.1\r\nhost: http://localhost\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n" >&3;grep "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" <&3
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with a TCP connection test to your internal service's port, you could use /dev/tcp for this:

`HEALTHCHECK CMD bash -c 'echo -n > /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/<port>'`

Like this:

```
# PASS (webserver is serving on 8099)
root@ab7470ea0c8b:/app# echo -n > /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8099
root@ab7470ea0c8b:/app# echo $?
0

# FAIL (webserver is NOT serving on 9000)
root@ab7470ea0c8b:/app# echo -n > /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/9000
bash: connect: Connection refused
bash: /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/9000: Connection refused
root@ab7470ea0c8b:/app# echo $?
1
```

Unfortunately, I think this is the best that can be done without installing curl or wget.